# should i use a long run first difference model or ADL

Tags: paneldata, health-economics

I have a panel data set with 30 countries and 40 years (1980-2020), and am interested in the long run relationship between several welfare program policy measures (e.g., how much income to programs replace, how progressive is the tax system) and life expectancy (LE)
I used a simple difference model taking each country change over the full period (ie value in 2020- value in 1980) for all variables: LE, my welfare measure, and some controls (income per person, health spend share of GDP, obesity rate), plus the level of LE in the first period.
so I have a 1 period model that looks like this

d.LE = d.welfare+d.income+d.obesity+d.health spending share + LE(1980)

The welfare measures are estimated in separate models that each include the above controls.
This is estimated with a simple cross sectional regression (n=20)

This approach produces large significant relationship for each welfare measure. I have tried adding and removing these controls and adding some others like that change in old age share of the population or the change in the rate of smoking in the country; but most of these results hold up quite well... there do not appear to be major outliers in added variable plots)
Call that Approach A

I have been told though that this is not a credible estimation strategy of the long run effect, and (because I have annual data for most of these variables)  I should use an ADL to get “more credible estimates” , and get my long run parameter estimates from this method...  e.g. (bx+bL.x + bL2.x...)/(1-bL.y-bL2.y...).
call this approach B
So getting iid errors in this ADL approach seems to require using 2 lags of Y (LE), two-way fixed effect estimates,and 2 lags of the Xs. (So I guess ADL(2,2)

Y = a+ b(X-1) + bX(t-2) + Y(t-1) Y(t-2) + bs for panel dummies + and bs for year dummies

The long run estimates are *very* different in this approach. One welfare variable is 50% higher than in Approach A; anouther is 2x larger, one welfare estimates are 4 times smaller and another flips sign,  All the new estimates are now statiatically significant (except one). (The estimated standard errors of long-run effect estimates in the ADL are relatively similar to the ones in Approach 1.)

So... there's the motivation for the question... the question is probably obvious. Is an ADL more appropriate here? I Admit that it may be more widely used over a long-run change model in Approach A, but I feel like it might just be a "slavish convention" thing than.  ON the other hand, is this just a case of seeing how biased APPROACH A can be?

I think it is fair to claim that for this problem we believe that, if there are long range effects of welfare provisions on health, the lag structure that may be inherently long and idiosyncratic by country (and perhaps period)